# SSH Tunnel Detection

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, firewall, tunnel

I have a query on SSH tunnel.

I have a low cost VPS on which I am running an SSH Server on port 443.  I use putty and create an SSH tunnel to bypass sites blocked.  In this regard I have some queries. Requesting anyone to answer it.

1. If I start an SSH connection will my ISP / sysadmin at work get to know?
2. Can the ISP / sysadmin get to know an SSH tunnel is created?
3. Will running the SSH server on port 443 make it kind of stealth look like normal HTTPS web traffic?
4. If no, then what is the way I could create a stealth SSH tunnel?

Looking forward to your inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If I start an SSH connection will my ISP / sysadmin at work get to know?

Yes, by seeing SSH protocol packets on port 22.

> Can the ISP / sysadmin get to know an SSH tunnel is created?

Probably, if they pay attention to the amount of traffic sent through that SSH connection. If your computer is receiving a lot of data through SSH, but isn't making any direct HTTP/HTTPS connections, they can guess you're using a tunnel to browse the web.

> Will running the SSH server on port 443 make it kind of stealth look like normal HTTPS web traffic?

No. HTTPS uses TLS, and SSH packets don't look anything like TLS ones. (They do however look very much like SSH packets.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: I would like to ask you how could I then make SSH stealth? AS I said I have my own VPS, anything could be done? and how do VPNs make VPN connections stealth,t they say that the make VPNs work over 443.  Please guide me on how to make ssh / ssh tunnel stealth